# Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have this error:

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.playtech.simulator:net:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<parent>
    <groupId>com.playtech.simulator</groupId>
    <artifactId>net</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.playtech.simulator.net</groupId>
<artifactId>server</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ogp</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.playtech.openapi.core</artifactId>
        <version>${ogw.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.9</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.playtech.simulator</groupId>
        <artifactId>simulator-app</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ogp</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.playtech.openapi.core.hazelcast</artifactId>
      <version>${ogw.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.ogp</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.playtech.openapi.core.frontend.http.socketio</artifactId>
        <version>${ogw.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>attached</goal>
                 </goals>
                 <phase>package</phase>
                 <configuration>
                   <descriptorRefs>
                     <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                  </descriptorRefs>
                  <archive>
                    <manifest>
                      <mainClass>com.playtech.openapi.simulator.SimulatorServer</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>
                </configuration>
             </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually a project's pom in the Parent section has this information, which you can easily see if you happen to use Eclipse:

- Group Id
- Artifact Id
- Version
- Relative Path

Relative path indicates the path respect the position of your project folder in the form, for example, `../main-project/parent`

In your pom there should be another line in your `<parent>` declaration:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.playtech.simulator</groupId>
    <artifactId>net</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>path-to-your-parent-project</relativePath>
</parent>
```

So revise your pom paying attention on where the projects are set.

Comment: parent project from SVN or local?

Comment: Similar issue is faced but command line build was successful. In eclipse it was giving above error. Small mistake was that maven path changed from C:\user\xxx\.m2 I have changed path to c:\mvn to shorten classpath.  This need to be changed in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Do install :

```
<groupId>com.playtech.simulator</groupId>
<artifactId>net</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can disable maven support in your project and provide those dependencies manually.This might be because the pom.xml is not getting parent pom.Hope it helps